# What does the broken link icon signify in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

What does the broken link icon signify in SonarQube?  In my environment it does link to a lower level project or source file. but does the broken link icon  signify that there is something broken in my configuration?  Is there a "whole" link icon (I've never seen one)?
Can't find any documentation on the iconography in general.  Point me there if it exists please.
[image: Broken Link Icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a permalink to that particular item: issue or rule.

Comment: Any reason the icon is a "broken" link? Or are we seeing this wrong?

Comment: The icon appears to me as a chain link broken into two pieces with some "sparks" highlighting the space between the pieces. Knowing the meaning is the most important as it was confusing some members of pilot group of developers.   I can now, with confidence, explain the meaning.

Comment: BTW, there's a ticket in to address this. You should see a change "soon": https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8591

Comment: Thank you I think the ideas attached to the ticket will be better.Very unexpected response.